# What do graders expect in a master thesis in pure mathematics?

Tags: thesis, mathematics, united-states, grades

I am writing a master thesis in pure mathematics the upcoming year and want to know what graders look for in a master thesis. I am in the US.

How do they grade the thesis? What are the things that can potentially lower my grade and what should I look out for?

Basically, in a pure mathematics master thesis they won't be expecting original research, and since I will be copying everything from the books in the bibliography, how can this go wrong?

I assume the presentation must also play a role, as for the grader to know whether I mindlessly copied the content without understanding the concepts or if I understood the topic.

Can you explain what the graders are looking for in a pure mathematics master thesis in order for me to ace the thesis?

Comment: Which country is this? In mine, a master's thesis in mathematics is very much expected to contain new results.

Comment: USA, I forgot to mention this is about pure mathematics not applied, do universities in your country expect new results in pure math, I would imagine this to be very hard, that is to prove an unproved theorem that professional mathematicians may struggle to prove in such a little time and limited experience.

Comment: UK here. I don't expect a new result, but I expect it written in your own way, new examples, your synthesis, your proofs and overall your understanding.

Comment: "my proofs" so should I find new ways to prove already proven theorems or just present the proofs given in my own way?

Comment: Can you have a look at theses written by previous students in your department?

Comment: At the American institutions where I have experience, a masters student has an advisor (and a committee).  The advisor (and committee) are responsible for setting the guidelines for a masters thesis.  You should talk with your advisor (and committee) about what *they* expect from you.

Comment: This is completely unanswerable on this forum. In the US, master's theses for mathematics are unusual, so it's even more true that it's up to your institution and your committee.